# Rails - passing params hash to js.erb file

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ajax, hash, parameters

I have a Rails 4 application and am trying to pass params[:search] captured from a form to the controller and ultimately to a js.erb file but the value of the hash is not going through.

sessions_controller.rb:

```
def home
  @persons = People.select("persons.name").where("persons.name LIKE ?", params[:search])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render :template => 'sessions/home.js.erb' }
  end
end
```

home.html.erb:

```
<%= @persons.to_sql %>

<%= form_tag home_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

<div id="persons">

</div>
```

_person_list.html.erb:

```
<%= person.name %><br>
```

home.js.erb file:

```
$('#persons').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'person_list', collection: @persons, as: 'person') %>");
console.log("<%= @persons.to_sql %>");
```

home.html.erb yields the following SQL snippet (which is expected):

```
WHERE (persons.name LIKE 'john')
```

But, from the code in the js.erb file, the developer console yields the following:

```
WHERE (persons.name LIKE NULL)
```

If I replace params[:search] in my controller with 'john' or if I set params[:search] = 'john', then the view file and js.erb file yield the same SQL snippet.  Also, if I leave off the .where statemnt in the controller, the code works as well and I believe that the problem has something to do with using the params[:search].  Using the code above, I can confirm that the url contains:

```
www.website.com/home?search=john
```

and that the debug container shows:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: ✓
search: john
controller: sessions
action: home
```

I've tried params[:search].to_s but that doesn't seem to work either.

Can somebody tell me how to pass the value of params[:search] to the js.erb file?  Thanks!

Comment: can you typed the code which you set params[:search] value ?

Comment: @Mohamed - the params[:search] value is submitted via a form.  I will update the question with the appropriate code.

Comment: @Iceman - I'm listing a bunch of names on home.js.erb and have a search box that allows users to search for a name in order to filter results.  Problem that I'm having is that my sql query is not returning the right results which is why I'm investigating '@persons.to_sql'...  Turns out that the WHERE clause differs between what I see home.html.erb vs. the results from home.js.erb.

Comment: Try to use `params['search']`, without `.to_s`

Comment: Just tried params['search'], params["search"] without .to_s but no luck.

Comment: did you work around with strong parameters ?

Comment: @knotito - pretty sure that params hash doesn't require the use of strong parameters.  Besides, my code works the controller responds to html (versus .js) requests.  Please let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: @Vee yes didn't noticed the method: 'get' in your form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Network panel in your browser's developer tools to inspect the AJAX request you're making to the `.js.erb` view. I think you'll find you're not passing a value for the `search` parameter.

If the fix for your JavaScript isn't obvious, go ahead and add that to your question and we can help you debug it.

Comment: James - you are exactly right.  The error had nothing to do with the code that was listed in the question.  Rather, it had to do with the AJAX call that I made in my javascript file - I wasn't passing the search parameter into the AJAX call (which I noticed in the Network panel since the url listed there was missing the search parameter) while the parameter was passed for the html response.  Additional +1 for showing me another debugging technique.